# Laravel dates localization showing always English

Tags: laravel, localization, locale

I have an issue with my Laravel project, where I applied localization package for text, but not working for dates as I understood need to be treated in a different way.
I all the project text is correctly translate according to the $locale, but dates as still in English.

I have following settings:

**config/app.php**

```
'locale' => 'en',
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

**HomeController@home**

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT.utf8');
echo strftime("%H:%M %A, %d %B");
```

Even with the above code I still read **16:59 Friday, 25 September** instead of **16:59 Venerdì, 25 Settembre**.

If I run `locale -a` in Terminal I see a lot of language as well as it_IT.

What am I missing to make the dates following my `app()->getLocale()`?

many thanks!

Comment: I don't think laravel auto-translates text for you

Comment: Me neither. But there are packages you can use for that, like https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-date. I would go for that.

Comment: When I try with `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');` it worked well. I don't know if `it_IT.utf8` is a valid locale but maybe you can give `it_IT` a shot.

Comment: Oh really you are right! `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');`, but now how to have all blades with  setlocale? I have MYSQL queries getting dates, but don't know how to show them according to the setlocale. How to apply set locale for the whole project?

Answer (score 0):

the original request was to understand how to apply the above localization by default to all pages of the project showing values like:

```
{{ $due_date }}
```

into the locale language.